# Разблокировка доменного имени на отдельном компьютере

Tags: windows, администрирование

Не силен в администрировании, потому сразу такой вопрос. Создал свой проект (коммерческий для бизнеса) на доменном имени nord-love.ru, однако столкнулся сразу с массой проблем, например с такой трудностью, что на компьютере обнаружилась блокировка именно данного доменного имени. Хотя пакеты идут нормально, и трассировка также выполняется без проблем. Интернет работает. Обращался в хостинг-компанию однако, они рапортовали, что веб-проект работает нормально и даже подтвердили корректность работы, что сразу стало ясно, что именно блокировки идут на данном компьютере.

В файле hosts также нет каких-либо ограничений данного доменного имени. Антивирус не выявляет никаких вирусов, троянов или червей. Брандмаузер работает, хотя его тоже в принципе можно блокировать. Точка доступа через вай-фай, с разных устройств виден домен и контент сайта, а с данного компьютера его не видно. Соответственно, блокировка идет на ПК. Операционная система Windows 8.1. Удаленный доступ был отрублен, чтобы пресечь все возможные способы вредительства компьютеру.

Что может блокировать компьютер? Как побороть эту черную заразу? Если это чей-то контроль, то как успешно заблокировать тех злоумышленников, кто пытается контролировать оборудование и саботирует работу на компьютере?

У меня предположения, что это на уровне провайдера блокировка по ip-адресу, либо это особенности ip-телефонии, либо в операционке идет контроль моей учетной записи, где тоже есть нюансы блокировок. Короче вопрос к знатокам администрирования, кто сталкивались с такими проблемами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть принципиальная разница в выводе запущенных команд: **nslookup nord-love.ru** и **nslookup nord-love.ru 8.8.8.8**?

Comment: Пишет, что не заслуживающий доверие домен. Скришот добавлен к вопросу

Comment: Ну что кто знает ответ?

Comment: Судя по приведенным результатам трассировок с разрешением имен проблем нет. Предположим, проблема локальная. причины: вредоносные плагины бразуера, некорректная работа сетевых фильтров МСЭ антивируса и пр. 1. Для начала попробовать другой браузер. 2. Попробовать использовать прокси: дополнениями, Turbo mode (хромиумные браузеры). 3. Отключить ненужные расширения браузера. 4. Попробовать приостановить работу антивируса.

Comment: @Daemon-5, винда 8.1, антивирус от системы. Плагины удалял в хроме, однако это никак не повлияло, тестировал в разных браузерах Explorer, Opera везде была такая же ерунда блокировка веб-контента. Предположительно это сетевой фильтр, либо какой-то вирус, что где-то блокирует мне. Тогда что мне посоветуете, чтобы избавиться от какого-либо черного контроля. Проект коммерческий и личный, считаю, что мою работу просто саботируют, ибо он перспективный. Проблема блокировки бывает связана с кешированием данных. Может тут, что проблема.?

Comment: Что насчет установки VPN-соединений и плагинов для обхода блокировок РКН, это было указано 2-м пунктом в моем предыдущем комментарии. Это было проделано?

Comment: @Daemon-5, в Опере использовал плагин Frigat для сетей, однако проблема сохраняется все также. По сути плагин Фригат - это и есть VPN-соединение, насколько я знаю... Или нет?

Comment: Это не совсем VPN, но реализация отчасти схожа. Ну я бы чисто ради спортивного интереса попробовал бы другие каналы связи на этом хосте. например,  подключил по дата-кабелю смартфон в режиме модем (RNDIS). И попробовал бы другое устройство (ноутбук/PC) на этом канале с аналогичными сетевыми настройками. Заодно поснифить трафик (Wireshark), чтобы понять на каком этапе искажаются данные.